# Не работает свойство position: sticky

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Не работает position: sticky.
Вот код:

```
.PageArticleAd {
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Вот страница https://bodybuilding-and-fitness.ru/journal/hobbi-bodibilderov.html
**Код только на мобильных.**
Не могу понять в чем дело, код находится в родительском контейнере, но по нему не двигается.

Вот скриншот блока, и его родителя, а также CSS кода.

[image: скрин]

Comment: 1. Родитель должен быть `relative`. 2. Должно быть место, по которому блок может двигаться (у Вас ниже контент, поэтому sticky-блок встанет не начав клеиться)

Comment: А я подсмотрел такой формат рекламы тут https://auto.ru/mag/article/v-kostrome-zapustili-rossiyskoe-proizvodstvo-abs-i-esp/ Тоже смотреть на мобильном. Вот скрин: https://disk.yandex.ru/i/kU-kQ_L6PqkInA

Comment: код надо вставлять как код, а не как картинку

Comment: @VladimirGonchar _Родитель должен быть relative._ - не обязательно